# Getting tag inside a classed div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with class `Foo` Inside of which is an achor tag.

```
 <div class="Foo">
    <a></a>
  </div>
```

How do I get all `<a>` inside `Foo`?

`$("a")` gets all the `<a>` in page.

Comment: This is like the `Hello World` of jQuery ... What did you try? Did you even search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this by class selector

```
$('.Foo a')
```

And you can also try

```
$('.Foo').find('a');
```

To iterate through every a you can try

```
$('.Foo a').each(function () {
   // do your stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this selector:

```
$(".Foo a")
```